# SQL Syntax Errors

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

I am working on a college SQL project and I encountered a syntax error while writing a event. The code is as following:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS InAndOut;
CREATE TABLE InAndOut(
Time            TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
Notification    VARCHAR (50));

DROP EVENT IF EXISTS NoOfCustomerIn;
DELIMITER //
CREATE EVENT NoOfCustomerIn
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 SECOND
DO
DECLARE vInCustomer Integer Default 0;
SET vInCustomer = ROUND((9 * RAND()), 0);
INSERT InAndOut(NoOfCustomerInAndOut) VALUES (Concat(vInCustomer, 'Customer comes!')); //
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

... and the error is:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near '**DECLARE vInCustomer
>   Integer Default 0; SET vInCustomer = ROUND((9 * RAND()), 0);**' at line 4

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I am not sure, but you might need to kill `//` at the and of the line: `INSERT InAndOut(NoOfCustomerInAndOut) VALUES (Concat(vInCustomer, 'Customer comes!')); //`

Comment: Tip: read the error message. There's a remote possibility that is related to the problem.

Comment: The error code is as follows: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE vInCustomer Integer Default 0; SET vInCustomer = ROUND((9 * RAND()), 0);' at line 4

Answer (score 0):

Change your variables to have an @ symbol before them.

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS InAndOut;
CREATE TABLE InAndOut(
Time            TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
Notification    VARCHAR (50));

DROP EVENT IF EXISTS NoOfCustomerIn;
DELIMITER //
CREATE EVENT NoOfCustomerIn
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 SECOND
DO
DECLARE @vInCustomer Integer Default 0;
SET @vInCustomer = ROUND((9 * RAND()), 0);
INSERT InAndOut(NoOfCustomerInAndOut) VALUES (Concat(@vInCustomer, 'Customer comes!')); //
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggests, you've written `DECLARE` at an unexpected (i.e. invalid) location:

```
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS NoOfCustomerIn;
DELIMITER //
CREATE EVENT NoOfCustomerIn
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 SECOND
DO
DECLARE vInCustomer Integer Default 0;
^^^^^^^
```

From the [`DECLARE` page in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare.html):

> DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements. Funny thing is that you already have the `END` part.

You're also closing the statement twice:

```
DELIMITER //
-- [...]
INSERT InAndOut(NoOfCustomerInAndOut) VALUES (Concat(vInCustomer, 'Customer comes!')); // -- Here
END; // -- And here
```